# Disable tcp checksum validation in Linux

Tags: linux, network-programming

Is there a way to disable TCP checksum validation in Linux. I am currently working on a network application and for testing purposes I need to be able to receive packets on the application level even if the TCP checksum was incorrect.

Note: the question is not about TCP checksum offloading but about a way to make sure the Linux kernel always delivers TCP packets to the application even if the checksum would be incorrect.

Comment: The TCP process requires the checksum to be valid, and it is built into the DNA of TCP. You would need to write your own TCP module to ignore the TCP checksum.

Comment: thanks @RonMaupin for the reply. The question was more about the implementation in Linux rather than the algorithm. The application I am working with uses programable switches that can not perform TCP checksums yet, therefore I would need to deactivate the validation on the client to test this current phase of the project(until checksum computation is available)

Comment: Applications do not perform the checksum. The point of TCP is that all that is hidden from the application, which just needs to bond to a TCP port. TCP handles all the ugly stuff, like setting up connections, checking data integrity, reordering segments, etc. All the application sees is the data stream.

Comment: In any case, checksums are an integral part of TCP, and disabling checksums would make it not TCP but something else (which you would need to write).